# question mark (?) quantifier for the whole word

Tags: regex

I have an amount of links like:

- https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F
- https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%3Futm_source

I need to capture the text before (%3F) sequence, and capture the whole line, if this sequence does not appear in the line. I want to do it without if-else condition applied for the whole line.

What am I looking for - is for an a way to apply a `?` quantifier for the whole character sequence, like this: `^(.*)[\%3F]?`

P.S. I know, that there is a way to work-around the problem by transforming the HTML-style characters into single ones first (`%2F -> "/" and %3F -> "?"`) and than applying `?` quantifier to a single character, but this is not the way I would like to solve the issue.

Comment: I suspect you want `^(?:(?!%3F).)*`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want but I think you're looking for `^.*?(?=%3F|$)`

Comment: Any feedback? What is the regex engine?

Comment: If you are using Go, you will need something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/70c7ltehxT).

Comment: Thanks guys. Both of them solve my problem. I was using this regex condition for a Python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?!%3F).)*
```

that will yield the same results as the following expression:

```
^.*?(?=%3F|$)
```

but the most efficient among these is their unrolled counterpart

```
^[^%]*(?:%(?!3F)[^%]*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/90uocG/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?!%3F).)*` - (a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)) any char but a line break char (`.`), zero or more consecutive occurrences , as many as possible (`*`), that does not start a `%3F` char sequence
- `.*?(?=%3F|$)` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars (`.*?`), as few as possible, up to but excluding `%3F` substring or up to the end of string (`$`).

The `^[^%]*(?:%(?!3F)[^%]*)*` pattern follows the unroll-the-loop principle where `[^%]*` matches any chars other than `%`, and `(?:%(?!3F)[^%]*)*` matches 0 or more sequences of `%` that is not followed with `3F` and then 0+ chars other than `%`. Since the lookahead condition only triggers upon a `%`, the performance is much better if the string is not overpopulated with `%` symbols (which should not be the case in real world).